# deploy terraform module all AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using the latest version of terraform and I'm trying to find a way to deploy an eventbridge forwarder to all regions in our AWS account.

I would like to do this dynamically so that when a new region gets created I don't need to update a static providers list.

I have the deployment in a module and I've been trying to loop over an aws_regions data section like this

```
data "aws_regions" "this" {}


module "eventbridge"{
  for_each = toset([for region in data.aws_regions.this.names : "aws.${region}"])
  source = "../../modules/eventbridge"
  region = each.value
}
```

And having a providers section in the module that uses the region variable, but providers in modules are no longer permitted and i'm out of ideas now!

Can anyone suggest a way this can be done?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do (looping through providers) is simply **not supported** by TF. You have to explicitly list all modules for each provider you want to use, or create some external script which is going to pre-process your TF code and do that automatically.

Alternatively, you can use CloudFormation Stack Sets which is an easy way to deploy AWS resources across multiple regions and accounts.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but was hoping wasn't the case!